# SharePoint - How to disable multiple clicks on Save button

Tags: sharepoint

I'm using a SharePoint 2013 list form that's OOTB. When I'm on the new item form, I noticed that if I click on the Save button multiple times, a list item is created per click. Is this a SharePoint bug? How can I disable it globally without having to modify each NewForm.aspx?
Thanks.

Comment: Similar question on SP.SE - http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/89177/20540.

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out. The solution they provided seems to only address it on a per form basis.

Answer (score 0):

Just Copy paste this code into your life without any editing it will work fine.And your work will be done.

```
$(document).ready(function(){


                 $("form").submit(function() {
                        $(this).submit(function() {
                            return false;
                        });
                        return true;
                    });
    });
```